# В чем разница между loop и while true?

Tags: while, rust

В чем разница между `loop` и `while true` в rust?

> В документации написано что:
>
> ```
> loop {}
> ```
>
> Интерпретируется по другому компилятором чем:
>
> ```
>  while true {}
> ```
>
> Хотел бы понять в чем эта разница и на сколько плохо использовать не `loop`, а `while true`

<sub>версия [вопроса на Английском](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28892351/what-is-the-difference-between-loop-and-while-true/) от @aij</sub>

Comment: Это изначально был перевод или случайно совпало?

Comment: ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/q/28892351/2881286

Comment: @Grundy случайно получилось, но решил ассоциация указать из вашего ответа

Answer (score 6, accepted):

На такой вопрос был дан ответ в [Reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/1v9rgp/rust_has_dowhile_loops/cer0ki4).

Разница заключается в том, что в случае `while true` все переменные должны быть инициализированы до цикла, а в случае `loop` это не обязательно:

> Пример с loop
>
> ```
> let x;
> loop { x = 1; break; }
> println!("{}", x)
> ```
>
> этот код отлично работает, однако следующий
>
> ```
> let x;
> while true { x = 1; break; }
> println!("{}", x);
> ```
>
> покажет ошибку компиляции "use of possibly uninitialised variable" с указанием на `x` в `println`. Во втором случае компилятор не определяет, что тело цикла всегда выполнится хотя бы один раз.

<sub>перевод [ответа @telotortium](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28892433/2881286)</sub>

Answer (score 5):

Сейчас есть еще одно отличие - из `loop` можно вернуть значение:

```
let x;
let y = loop { x = 1; break 42;};
println!("x={} y={}", x, y);
```

[Returning from loops](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/appendix-06-newest-features.html#returning-from-loops)